# "Не()понятно" — слитно или раздельно?

Tags: орфография, частица-не

"Мне это всегда было не()понятно" — я пишу раздельно и всякий раз сомневаюсь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Раздельное написание здесь возможно, но в случае когда, как писал Розенталь, в предложении содержится, подчеркивается отрицание (я отрицаю, что мне это понятно). А обычно это предложение пишется со словом "непонятно" в модальном значении. Здесь нет противопоставления,слово "непонятно" можно заменить синонимом без НЕ, поэтому частица НЕ пишется слитно